# I use hugo build static page. But don't have content

Tags: hugo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ENNas.png)

Deploy don't have error.
But there's nothing on my page.

https://sillyhatxu.github.io/

Comment: It just have my web page, but nothing content.

Comment: I need update  "draft" to false

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the parameters

```
draft: false
```

For Example

```
---
title: "Golang bit operation"
subtitle: "Golang 位运算"
date: 2019-05-27T23:13:11+08:00
author: "one_zheng"
tags: ["golang","algorithm"]
categories: ["golang"]
from: "https://medium.com/learning-the-go-programming-language/bit-hacking-with-go-e0acee258827"
draft: false
---
```